# Using Fluent NHiberanate how do I turn off the mapping of a non persistent property

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

All my persistent objects have a property which should not be persisted.

At this moment i generate my automapping like this:

```
var autoMap = 
     AutoMap.AssemblyOf<BaseEntity>()
    .Where(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Contains("Models"))
    .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<IEntity>()
    .OverrideAll(map => map.IgnoreProperty("IsDummy"));
```

However the following error is returned:

> System.TypeInitializationException:
>   System.TypeInitializationException:
>   The type initializer for
>   'Core.Context' threw an exception.
>   ---> NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException:
>   The following types may not be used as
>   proxies: Core.Models.MyEntity: method
>   get_IsDummy should be
>   'public/protected virtual' or
>   'protected internal virtual'

This leads me to believe that the override did not work.
(Core.Context is the class triggering the mapping process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a property virtual, even if it not mapped. Otherwise, NHibernate can't properly generate proxy for lazy loading your object.